# GA4 Reports Builder for Google Analytics - How to make a Filter?

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

[GA4 Reports Builder](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/ga4_reports_builder_for_google_analytics/589269949355)

I'm having a problem understanding how to make a filter in a report.

Basically I want to get only data from "facebook / cpc" in a report, but following the guides from this page (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema?hl=pt-br), i couldn't do it.

[How i tried to insert the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7l8a.png)

The way I'm doing it doesn't filter anything.

Comment: I have sent a request off to the team that they update it.   I will let you know when I hear back it may be on their road map.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation for that add-on, instead use GA4 Magic Report for Google Sheets which works perfectly and you can build the filters from the interface:

https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/ga4_magic_reports/6532356327

Comment: [What constitutes an affiliation disclosure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360418/244647)

Comment: Thanks Linda for the reminder, mine is the immediate solution (free), if you think it's spam I can change the answer to: I'm sorry but there is no documentation, try other tools.